Not able to define same template variable twice in the angular template
I have a query regarding the template variable in angular. Actually I was trying to access multiple elements with the help of the @ViewChildren() decorator.
But when I was defining two element with the same template variable name like below example

then i was getting error below error

But when I wrapped both the elements with the div like below

then it started working fine and i was able to access both elements with @ViewChildren() decorator.
So I just wanted to know what is happening here? I mean whenever we want to use same template variable more than once do we need to always wrap them or what?
Can anyone explain what I am missing here?
Thanks
I tried googling but I did not get any proper reason for this behavior. So I just want to understand how template variable works.
this question is similar to this question
Template parse errors: Reference "#XXX" is defined several times in angular
but, they also did not provide any reason why it is working after wrapping inside the div.

This question is similar to: Template parse errors: Reference "#XXX" is defined several times in angular. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JSONDerulo did not explain the reason of the above behavior. they just said it is a trick.

did I answered your question?

@AakashGiri Could you share a stackblitz where the issue happens?

@JSmith Yes, partially because you have suggested a different approach. I mean in your example you are using two different template variables. But my question was regarding if we use the same template variables then why do we get error? and when we wrap it inside the div then error gets resolved.
I think it is somewhere related to the ng-template maybe

@JSmith It makes sense to not use the same template variable twice because how will angular know which template variable it should target? But after wrapping both the template variables it is working this means somehow now both the template variables get isolated. I don't know how they are getting isolated and angular is now able to recognize them. Maybe is somewhere related to the ng-template

@NarenMurali I was using angular 8. I did not get this issue with angular 12. So You are right this is an angular bug that was resolved in angular 12.

@AakashGiri Well I'm just refering to the doc.Using the same variable twice even if that doesn't throw an error look like it is a bad practice. So if you want multiple elements with the same ref bound to it I guess the only good practice for that is to use @for loop.

@JSmith Yes, you are right, it is a bad practice to use the same template variable twice even if it is not throwing an error. We should always use unique template variables. But I was curious to know, why it was behaving that way I mean it was throwing an error in my case but was working for others(YouTube tutorial). Now I got to know from NarenMurali's answer that was a bug that got fixed in angular 12.

Seems like a bug in earlier versions of Angular. This bug seems to be fixed for angular versions >12.0.0-next.0

I found the issues which contains some clarity as to why this error might be present and why it was removed.
Duplicate template reference variables are not treated as error with Ivy
fix(compiler): throw error for duplicate template references

This issue in replicable in angular 8 -> Stackblitz Demo
But not in angular 18 -> Stackblitz Demo
So JSmith answer is good for angular 8+, for latest versions of angular this error does not happen!

the angular doc says

Define the variable only once in the template so the runtime values remains predictable

If you want to assign multiple variables the correct syntax would be
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div #child1>Content of child 1</div>
    <div #child2>Content of child 2</div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren('child1, child2') children!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.children.forEach((child) => {
      console.log(child.nativeElement.textContent);
    });
  }
}

